# type mismatch for sbt task/setting keys

Tags: scala, sbt, type-mismatch

I am following the sbt documentation's tutorial and at this chapter: [Defining a task that depends on other settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Task-Graph.html#Defining+a+task+that+depends+on+other+settings), there is such exmaple:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Hello",
    organization := "com.example",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.3",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalacOptions := List("-encoding", "utf8", "-Xfatal-warnings", "-deprecation", "-unchecked"),
    scalacOptions := {
      val old = scalacOptions.value
      scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
        case "2.12" => old
        case _      => old filterNot (Set("-Xfatal-warnings", "-deprecation").apply)
      }
    }
  )
```

> *scalacOptions is a task key. Let’s say it’s been set to some values already, but you want to filter out "-Xfatal-warnings" and "-deprecation" for non-2.12.*

And it should be running as following:

```
> show scalacOptions
[info] * -encoding
[info] * utf8
[info] * -Xfatal-warnings
[info] * -deprecation
[info] * -unchecked
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 2, 2017 11:44:44 PM
> ++2.11.8
[info] Setting version to 2.11.8
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to Hello (in build file:/xxx/)
> show scalacOptions
[info] * -encoding
[info] * utf8
[info] * -unchecked
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 2, 2017 11:44:51 PM
```

**However**, what I got is the following in IntelliJ, and it looks like there are more than one issues:

[image]
[image]

This is not an IntelliJ issue:

```
$sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/fluency03/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/fluency03/Workplace/flink/flink-project/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/fluency03/Workplace/flink/flink-project/project
[error] [/Users/fluency03/Workplace/flink/flink-project/build.sbt]:42: illegal character '\u00a0'
[error] [/Users/fluency03/Workplace/flink/flink-project/build.sbt]:43: illegal character '\u00a0'
[error] [/Users/fluency03/Workplace/flink/flink-project/build.sbt]:45: illegal character '\u00a0'
[error] [/Users/fluency03/Workplace/flink/flink-project/build.sbt]:46: illegal character '\u00a0'
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I have had another try:

[image]

VS.

[image]

And it seems like the `scalacOptions` was first given as a `List`, after that, it cannot be given as a different signature like `{}`. But my confusions are:

- `scalacOptions` itself is actually a `sbt.TaskKey[scala.Seq[scala.Predef.String]]`
- if the different signature thing is not working, then how the documentation of sbt is ok?

Comment: does this work in sbt? Is only an IntelliJ problem?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella it is not intellij issue, please see the question update.

Comment: the error you see seems a character encoding error. Have you copy-pasted the source from somewhere? Try re-writing it manually

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I've updated the question accordingly